# Transforming columns of unequal arrays to column of single values in R

Tags: r, tidyr

As a next step after this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910362/transforming-a-column-of-arrays-to-column-of-single-values-in-r), assume that there are multiple columns of arrays that do not have the same length. For example:

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [0.1,0.5,0.7] | [1.54E12, 1.54E12, 1.54E12] | [1, 3, 4, 5} |

How can I take this format and reformat it to the following giving NAs to Col_A and Col_b where appropriate:

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 1.54E12 | 1 |
| 0.5 | 1.54E12 | 3 |
| 0.7 | 1.54E12 | 4 |
| NA | NA | 5 |

This code works for when all arrays are equal but will throw an error if the arrays are not equal:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df  %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), str_extract_all, "(?<=\\[)[^]]+")) %>% 
   unnest(c(NDVIs, dates)) %>% 
   separate_rows(c(NDVIs, dates), sep=",\\s+", convert = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
cSplit(setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = "[][}]", 
    replacement = "")], names(df), sep=",", fixed = FALSE, "long")
#   Col_A    Col_B Col_C
#1:   0.1 1.54e+12     1
#2:   0.5 1.54e+12     3
#3:   0.7 1.54e+12     4
#4:    NA       NA     5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col_A = "[0.1,0.5,0.7]", Col_B = "[1.54E12, 1.54E12, 1.54E12]", 
    Col_C = "[1, 3, 4, 5}"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough experience with the `tidyverse` here, so here is my solution with `data.table`. I included all in between steps and results, to show what is going on...

```
library( data.table )
#create sample data
DT <- fread("Col_A  Col_B   Col_C
[0.1,0.5,0.7]   [1.54E12, 1.54E12, 1.54E12]     [1, 3, 4, 5]")
#            Col_A                       Col_B        Col_C
# 1: [0.1,0.5,0.7] [1.54E12, 1.54E12, 1.54E12] [1, 3, 4, 5]

#melt to long format
ans <- melt( DT, measure.vars = names(DT), variable.factor = FALSE )
#    variable                       value
# 1:    Col_A               [0.1,0.5,0.7]
# 2:    Col_B [1.54E12, 1.54E12, 1.54E12]
# 3:    Col_C                [1, 3, 4, 5]

#remove [] and split the value column using ', ' as sepatator
ans[, value := gsub( "\\[|\\]", "", value ) ]
ans[, paste0( "v", 1:length( tstrsplit(ans$value, "," ) ) ) := 
      lapply( tstrsplit(value, "," ), as.numeric ) ][]
#    variable                     value       v1       v2       v3 v4
# 1:    Col_A               0.1,0.5,0.7 1.00e-01 5.00e-01 7.00e-01 NA
# 2:    Col_B 1.54E12, 1.54E12, 1.54E12 1.54e+12 1.54e+12 1.54e+12 NA
# 3:    Col_C                1, 3, 4, 5 1.00e+00 3.00e+00 4.00e+00  5

#transpose (without value-columns) to get wide format again
transpose( ans[, -"value"], make.names = "variable" )
#    Col_A    Col_B Col_C
# 1:   0.1 1.54e+12     1
# 2:   0.5 1.54e+12     3
# 3:   0.7 1.54e+12     4
# 4:    NA       NA     5
```

Comment: This worked for me until the transpose bit, I think I was doing something wrong and was about to reformat it with the ```pivot_longer``` function but the second answer worked nicely. Thanks for your time!